# gobject signals emitted at constuction time

Tags: signals, gobject

I have a problem with emiting a signal at construction time. Either I miss the signal because the handler is connected after construction time or signals are not emitted at all at this stage.
Here's a stripped down example where a signal is emitted twice, but only registered once:

```
#include <glib-object.h>

GType dummy_get_type(void);

#define DUMMY_TYPE (dummy_get_type())
#define DUMMY(obj) (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST((obj), DUMMY_TYPE, Dummy))

enum {
    TEST,
    LAST_SIGNAL,
};

static guint signals[LAST_SIGNAL] = { 0 };

typedef struct {
    GObject parent;
} Dummy;

typedef struct {
    GObjectClass parent_class;
} DummyClass;

Dummy *dummy_new(void) {
    return DUMMY(g_object_new(DUMMY_TYPE, NULL));
}

void dummy_emit(Dummy *self) {
    g_signal_emit((gpointer)self, signals[TEST], 0);
}

static void dummy_init(Dummy *self) {
    dummy_emit(self);
}

static void dummy_class_init(DummyClass *klass) {
    signals[TEST] = g_signal_new("test", DUMMY_TYPE,
            G_SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST | G_SIGNAL_ACTION, 0, NULL, NULL,
            g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__VOID, G_TYPE_NONE, 0);
}

G_DEFINE_TYPE(Dummy, dummy, G_TYPE_OBJECT);

void test_callback(Dummy *dummy, gpointer user_data) {
    g_message("test emitted");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    g_type_init();

    Dummy *dummy = dummy_new();
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(dummy), "test", G_CALLBACK(test_callback), NULL);

    dummy_emit(dummy);

    return 0;
}
```

My question: What's the best practice to get this working?
Two ways that come to my mind:

1. Adding a timer or idle handler that emits the signal later.
2. Establishing start/stop functions to delay doing things after construction time.

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, you cannot connect to a signal emission on an instance if you don't have an instance, and the only code that has access to an instance during construction is the class code itself, which does not need to use signals. For all intent and purposes, `g_object_new()` is an atomic operation, from the perspective of a caller. For that reason, you don't usually emit signals or notify on property changes during the instance construction phase.

If you use a timeout or an idle source, you'll also need to spin the main loop, which is usually not recommended for generic objects.

The usual design pattern is to create an instance in an "inert" state, and use a method to begin broadcasting signals and changing properties. The same "inert" state is also what you return to when inside the `dispose()` virtual function implementation.